# Change login name containing my email adress

Tags: support, user-accounts

In 2016 I created an Ask Ubuntu account with a login containing my email adress. I recently changed my email, how can I change to a new login name without losing my Ask Ubuntu history?

Comment: Your login name is "newbie". Is that what you mean? Or do you just want to update the email address associated with your account?

Answer (score 5):

goto profiles > edit profiles (top right corner)> your logins > add login

[image: edit profiles > yourlogin]

[image: yourlogin> add login]

[image: add login > give email id and a new password]